# Is it generally better to learn Latin first?

Tags: latin

Is it generally better to learn Latin first then deductively learn french, spanish, etcetera or to go vice versa and inductively learn latin? Please provide a reason why, as I seek to decide on a language to hard-focus on.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "better"? Better in what way?

Comment: Your question is closed at the moment because it seems that the [Latin, Italian, or French?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2814/800) already seems to provide what you want to know. If this is not the case, please edit your question so as to make clear how it differs from the other question. Note that "better" would then still need to clarified.

Comment: See also [How useful is studying Latin for learners of more than one Romance language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/114/800)